# ./autogen.sh gives : invalid option

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I want to add libcrafter file in cpp file which is provided from https://github.com/pellegre/libcrafter In that they provide steps

```
cd libcrafter/libcrafter

$ ./autogen.sh 

$ make

$ sudo make install

$ sudo ldconfig
```

But when I run command it gives invalid option

I have already installed

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf libtool

sudo apt-get install libpcap0.8 libpcap0.8-dev 

#!/bin/sh -e

test -n "$srcdir" || srcdir=`dirname "$0"`

test -n "$srcdir" || srcdir=.

autoreconf --force --install --verbose "$srcdir"

test -n "$NOCONFIGURE" || "$srcdir/configure" "$@"
```

Error:

```
libcrafter$ sudo ./autogen.sh
[sudo] password for altaf: : invalid option
```

Comment: *"But when I run command it gives invalid option"*... Paste your error.

Comment: altaf@altaf-Lenovo-G50-70:~/CNProjactProgram/libcrafter/libcrafter$ sudo ./autogen.sh 
[sudo] password for altaf: 
: invalid option
altaf@altaf-Lenovo-G50-70:~/CNProjactProgram/libcrafter/libcrafter$

Comment: sudo ./autogen.sh 
[sudo] password for altaf: 
: invalid option

To simplify i have remove path

Comment: ? Why run `$ sudo ./autogen.sh` ,,, when the text says `$ ./autogen.sh` ? The 'sudo' is for administrative tasks only. Please do not use 'sudo' for building software. ...

Comment: i used it because its says that permission denied but ya after changing its permission it is running thanx.